# I broke an oath (qasam)

Tags: allah, sunni, jannah, forgiveness, jahannam

Assalam o alaikum . I am a Muslim girl and since i was 12 , i did not know that breaking.a qasam is so bad , i broke many oaths with Allah bcz i thought i will just repent i was baligh and now i know that it is a very big sin and i also have to pay kaffara for it. I am still young so i will talk to my family about paying kaffara , my father will do something about it and now i will never break any oath with Allah . I have asked Allah for forgiveness but im scared and worried and i broke so many oaths that i dont even remember the exact number so how can i pay the exact kaffaraa. Will Allah forgive me

Answer (score 1):

Yes with a sincere repentance I think it’s only 3 days if it’s the same. Just don’t promise Allah something you can’t keep from now on. Allah is most forgiving most merciful never lose hope. Allah knows best.

Comment: Can i pay amount (money) for kaffara. I would have fasted for 3 days but i cant and nevertheless ,  money is the first option. Please tell me do i have to pay money for all oaths? They were too many we cant afford

Comment: You can give food to 3 poor people and that’s another option.

Comment: Oh ok InshAllah I will. Thank you. I have tried many websites and nobody gave me an answer. I was hopeless.

Comment: Never ever thing that way there is always a way out of a sin major or minor.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you are not considered accountable for a sin unless you know about it being a sin, Its severance, and Its punishment in your consciousness.

Remember, you did not know that breaking the oath is such a big sin back then, so the punishment won't account for you. Also, each and every single sin even killing someone or adultery can be forgiven on sincere repentance the only sin in Islam that cannot be forgiven is disrespect of the Prophet (PBUH), his companions, and Allah knowingly, that's it. Even If you commit the worst crime they can be forgiven upon sincere repentance and not doing them again.